# Pseudo serial connection for testing

Tags: linux, serial-port

There is an application which wirtes to a serial connection and reads from a serial connection. I am testing it and can not change it. My test environment contains two computers and applications on that two computers send something to each other over the serial connection. I want to create a pseudo serial connection in order to test on only one computer. So that, one application will write to that pseudo serial connection and the other one, which is on the same computer, will read it.

Is such a pseudo serial connection possible? My test computer has only one serial connection but if it is required I can use a virtual machine which has got two serial connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use USB-to-RS232 adapters to get additional COM ports.  Hook your two COM ports together with a null modem cable.  Then your test program can open one port and talk to your app under test.

Comment: @sawdust, it's no big deal, but "virtual com port" is the correct terminology.  Most of those cables have FTDI chips in them, and their documentation calls them virtual: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm   They are "virtual" because your actual PC hardware is still just a USB port, but the FTDI driver software on your PC makes it look like a regular COM port.  But I agree that for all practical purposes it's no different

Answer (score 3):

i found this com0com. http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/files/com0com/3.0.0.0/

It will create two virtual serial ports. You can test it by using two Putty windows. Just chose different COM port.
Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks but as far as i can see it is for windows